# Calculate Treatment Effect for the Treated

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

This is from the paper 1991 Identification and Estimation of Local Average Treatment Effects by Angrist and Imbens.

On p5, example 1 which says:

Consider the following model:

$Y_0 = \epsilon$

$Y_1 = Y_0 + \eta$

$D_z = h(z, \nu)$

where, $Y_0$ is the potential outcome for treatment $D = 0$ (i.e. control) and $Y_1$ is the potential outcome for treatment $D = 1$ (i.e. treatment).

The treatment $D$ is binary and takes value $0$ or $1$.

$Z$ is an instrumental variable that is uncorrelated with the outcome but correlated with the treatment.

Therefore, the treatment $D$ is a function of the instrumental variable $Z$.
$(\epsilon, \eta, \nu)$ are jointly independent of $Z$.

Let $Z\in \{0, 1\}$ be binary, and $\nu \in \{0, 1, 2\}$ with $Pr(\nu = 0) = 2/7, Pr(\nu = 1) = 4/7, Pr(\nu = 2) = 1/7$.

Let $E[\eta|\nu = 0] = E[\eta|\nu = 1] = 1$ and $E[\eta|\nu = 2] = 2$.

The conditional expectation of $\epsilon$ satisfied $E[\epsilon|\nu = 0] = 1, E[\epsilon|\nu = 1] = 5/2, E[\epsilon|\nu = 2] = 0$.

Finally, let $h(.,.)$ satisfy: $h(1, 0) = h(0, 2) = 1$ and $h(0, 0) = h(0, 1) = h(1, 1) = h(1, 2) = 0$.

The participation probability $P_z$ is 2/7 for people with $Z = 0$ and 1/7 for people with $Z = 1$.

Now they calculated the selected average treatment effect $\alpha_1$ given by $\alpha_1 = E[Y_1 - Y_0|D = 1]$ to be $2/[Pr(Z = 0) + 1]$.

I can not get the same answer and wondering if someone could help! Thanks in advance!